# Something ready or something is ready - is there a difference?

Tags: grammar

I have been confused with this phrase in Red Alert 2 game, where it sounds like "Unit ready" or "Nuclear missile ready". As far as I know, ready is a adjective, so it is used like "I'm ready, you are ready, unit is ready" etc, isn't it?

Answer (score -1):

"Unit ready" is a contraction of "The unit is ready".  Strictly speaking it's ungrammatical, but may be acceptable (or even expected) in a context where communication is preferred to be as terse as possible, such as communication between the military, which this game imitates.

Comment: That is not correct. "Ready" meaning immediately available can be used here as in "ready cash," "weapon ready, "" unit ready"etc.

Comment: @vickyace i don't understand your point, sorry:  are you saying that "Unit ready" **is** a grammatically correct complete sentence?

Comment: Actually there are two questions asked by the op, even if he isn't aware of it: Is the term "unit ready" acceptable usage and why it has been used here in such a way instead of the conventional "Subject is adjective" form. You didn't consider the part where ready means something is available at this moment prepared for use or alike.

Comment: I'd assume that "x ready" is a contraction for either "x is ready" or "x: ready" as a statement.

Comment: @vickyace - the case when ready means "available at this moment" **is** what i was referring to.  I don't know what other case there is, since that's the meaning of the word.  Since I haven't understood either of your comments it might be best if you lay your argument out in an answer: then you will be able to explain it more clearly, i think.

Comment: @vickyace There is an other example of the same kind. I don't want to make a new question, so I ask it here. Consider phrase "resident secure", pronounced by the vault computer in Fallout 4 game, when player stepped in the cryogenic capsule. Why it is not "resident is secured"?

Comment: @jumpjet67 This mostly military format has migrated into civilian usage by dint of cinemas and other media. *Resident secure* may not be approved by scholars but it is easily understood colloquially.